# D3 --> React translation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, react-apollo, react-animated

I am trying to turn this graph https://bl.ocks.org/scresawn/0e7e4cf9a0a459e59bacad492f73e139, into a react component.  So far what I have is not rendering anything to the screen.  If someone can take a look and make suggestions on improving the code that would be great. Also, I will be passing data to the component from another component instead fetching a CSV file.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
        class ScaleTime extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
    };
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(data)
            .then( (response) => {
                return response.json() })   
                    .then( (json) => {
                        this.setState({data: json});
                    });
    };

    //What is happening here?
    componentWillMount(){
        d3.csv("phage-history.csv", function (error, data) {


            svgEnter = svg.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter();

            svgEnter.append("rect")
            .attr("rx", 25)
            .attr("x", function (d) {
              x = xScale(new Date(d.start));
              return x;
            })
            .attr("y", function(d, i) { return 400 - (d.count*30); })
            .attr("width", 25)
            .attr("height", 25)
            .attr("fill", "green")
            .attr("stroke-width", "1px")
            .attr("stroke", "black")
            .on("mouseover", function (d) {
              rect = d3.select(this);
              rect.transition()
              .duration(500)
              .attr("y", function(d, i) { 
                console.log(this);
                var x = rect.x;
                return 20; })
              .transition()
              .duration(500)
              .attr("rx", 2)
              .attr("width", 300)
              .attr("height", 100)
                .attr("fill", "skyblue");

                  tooltip.html(d.authors + "<br>" + d.description);
              tooltip
                .style("top", 30)
                .style("left",function () {
                console.log("x", x);
                return d3.event.pageX;
              })
                  setTimeout(function () { 
                tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");
              }, 1500);
            })
              .on("mouseout", function (d) {
              d3.select(this)
              .transition()
              .duration(500)
              .attr("rx", 25)
              .attr("width", 25)
              .attr("height", 25)
              .transition()
              .duration(500)
              .delay(500)
              .attr("y", function(d, i) { return 400 - (d.count*30); })
              .attr("fill", "green");
                  //tooltip.text(d.authors);
              return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");

            });
          });
    }//componentWillMount

    componentDidUpdate() {
        var tooltip = d3.select("body")
        .append("div")
            .style("font-size", "12px")
            .style("width", 285)
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("z-index", "10")
        .style("visibility", "hidden");

        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("width", 960)
          .attr("height", 500);

    var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([new Date("January 1, 1940 00:00:00"), new Date("January 4, 1980 00:00:00")])
      .range([20, 900]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ScaleTime">
                <svg width="960" height="500" />




svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,450)")
  .call(xAxis);

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: don't do your main stuff in `componentWillMount` but in `componentDidMount`, don't create a new tooltip every time you get an update.

Comment: I updated the code but I am still stuck at `d3.csv("phage-history.csv", function (error, data) {` Not sure how to access data that is passed as props from another component here instead of using the d3.cvs.

Comment: Added some more edits.

Comment: Any suggestions...?